# How to useFetch with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating an application with react. I have to fetch several data.
This is my fetch statement:

```
const [periods] = useFetch('/company/' + slug + '/waterfall?colIndexOffset=6 ');
```

At the end of the line, it is a `6` but I have this kind of problem. I have periods and these periods are changed for every object.

```
const [period_waterfall] = useFetch('/company/' + firminfo.code + '/periods');
```

I call the period from there and I find the length of periods like this:

```
var length = period_waterfall.periods.length
```

I should call this `periods` fetch multiple times (number of `length`).

I tried this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        my_array.push(useFetch('/company/' + slug + '/waterfall?colIndexOffset=' + i))
      }
```

But it gives error: React Hook "useFetch" may be executed more than once. Possibly because it is called in a loop.

How can I handle it?

Comment: [First rule of Hook Club](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level): "Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions".

Comment: @Andy I don't wanna be a rule breaker but I do not know What should I do

Comment: You can rewrite the useFetch, or write a useLoopFetch that does this within the hook instead.

Comment: @StephanBakkelundValois I cannot find anything about useLoopFetch

Comment: Find? You need to write it yourself. Why can't you just fetch the data the regular way, instead of using a hook? Is there a particular reason you're using a hook for this operation? As you can see, you're using a prebuilt hook that doesn't fit your need. You should drop it and either write your own hooks, or just write functions that fetches your data with axios for example

Comment: @StephanBakkelundValois I am new to React but I will try to write

Comment: I'll write you an answer with some tips

Comment: What is `useFetch`, where did you define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call a hook within a loop. This is a bad practice and is not allowed. Hooks should always be called at the top level.

You're also using a predefined hook for data retrieval. This hook is meant to do one fetch. In your particular order, you need to do this in a loop operation, which means the hook you're using doesn't fit your need.

What you can do, is create a function that does the fetching instead of using the hook. I like to use axios.

```js
const getPeriods = async (offset, slug) => {
  const url = '/company/' + slug + '/waterfall?colIndexOffset=' + offset
  const response = await axios.get(url)
  return response.data
}
```

In this function, you are fetching 1 item. You may rewrite it so that you do the looping inside of it, or you can call it inside a loop

```js
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  my_array.push(await getPeriods(i, slug)
}
```

Note that the loop is using `await` which means it needs to be inside an async function. If you don't want that, you can always do something like this:

```
getPeriods(i, slug).then((res) => {
  my_array.push(res.data)
}
```

Hope this helps solving your issue.